# How to speed up the calculations of the Gröbner basis of the following system of equations?

Tags: groebner-bases

Consider the following ideal:

```
    ideal = {-z + z0, -a - k1 x - k4 x^2 - y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) - 
   k3 z - (k8 x + k9 y) z - k6 z^2 + z1, -k1 y - 2 k4 x y - k7 y^2 - 
   k2 z - k7 x z - 2 k5 y z - k8 y z - k9 z^2 - 
   k3 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   k8 x (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   k9 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   2 k6 z (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
   z2, -2 k4 y^2 - k1 z - 2 k4 x z - 3 k7 y z - 2 k5 z^2 - k8 z^2 - 
   k2 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   k7 x (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   2 k5 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   2 k8 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   3 k9 z (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) - 
   2 k6 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
      y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2)^2 - 
   k3 (k1 y + 2 k4 x y + k7 y^2 + k2 z + k7 x z + 2 k5 y z + k8 y z + 
      k9 z^2 + 
      k3 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k8 x (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k9 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      2 k6 z (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2)) - 
   k8 x (k1 y + 2 k4 x y + k7 y^2 + k2 z + k7 x z + 2 k5 y z + 
      k8 y z + k9 z^2 + 
      k3 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k8 x (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k9 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      2 k6 z (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2)) - 
   k9 y (k1 y + 2 k4 x y + k7 y^2 + k2 z + k7 x z + 2 k5 y z + 
      k8 y z + k9 z^2 + 
      k3 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k8 x (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k9 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      2 k6 z (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2)) - 
   2 k6 z (k1 y + 2 k4 x y + k7 y^2 + k2 z + k7 x z + 2 k5 y z + 
      k8 y z + k9 z^2 + 
      k3 (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k8 x (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      k9 y (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2) + 
      2 k6 z (a + k1 x + k4 x^2 + 
         y (k2 + k7 x + k5 y) + (k3 + k8 x + k9 y) z + k6 z^2)) + z3}
```

I am using the following command to eliminate the variables `x`, `y`and `z`, but it is taking too long:

```
GroebnerBasis[ideal, {x, y, z, z0, z1, z2, z3}, {x, y, z}, 
 MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder]
```

Is there a way to speed up the calculations?  Or to monitor them? `k1` to `k9` and `a` are unknown constants (rationals).

Many thanks.

Comment: ...why are `x, y, z` both in the second and third argument, if you're eliminating them? Try removing them from the second argument. Also, have you experimented with other settings for `MonomialOrder`?

Comment: Many thanks for pointing my mistake.   I have removed x, y and z fro the second argument.  As for the second question, yes I have and does not make much difference.   Is there a way to indicate that k1 to k9 and a are constants?

Comment: To indicate constants, one can use `CoefficientDomain->RationalFunctions`. Not sure if that will improve the speed situation in this instance though.